# Get Position of TabItems within a TabControl that uses drag/drop

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I want to save the configuration of a `TabControl`. For that I need to know at which position which tab is opened. The `TabItems` can be moved around within the `TabControl` (drag and drop). Therefore, the collection bound to `ItemsSource` is not at the correct order.

How do I know which `TabItem` is opened at which Index?

For drag/drop I am using https://github.com/ButchersBoy/Dragablz

Comment: How is it that TabItems can be moved around?  You have a drag and drop on your TabItems?  I use SelectIndex all the time and it has never gotten out of order for me.

Comment: @Frisbee, yes I use drag and drop using this library https://github.com/ButchersBoy/Dragablz

Comment: Then that would be some detail to include IN the question.